# get file count based on last modified dates

Tags: powershell

I am looking for some PowerShell script where I can get the count of the files in a directory and come up with a count summary as below:

```
Date                 Number of files             Size
26-Feb                  100                      100MB
25-Feb                  250                      12MB
24-Feb                  300                      97MB
```

Basically I want to get the count based on a particular last modified date and group them.

I tried many things incluing `dir /A-D` from cmd and in PowerShell `GET-ChildItem` and tried combination of these further to pipe and get the desired output but couldn't get it.

Comment: Where is the `Date` info coming from? File modified date?

Comment: Yes, file last modified date. Thanks,

Comment: File modified date or Directory modified date?

Comment: Ok so file modified date, number of files in the directory and the size of the file. Is that right?

Comment: yes I guess, basically I am looking for count of total number of files on a modified date like I displayed in  the summary like 6k File has last modified date is 26 feb and their total size is 100 MB. Similarly 5.5 K files - last modified date is 25 Feb and their total size is 12 MB and so on

Comment: thank you for putting the time and effort in this.

Comment: You're welcome, just want to make sure we understand the question...looks like mjolinor beat me to it. He has a good solution.

Comment: Solved now. Thanks for putting the effort in it. Really Appreciate it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm sure there's a group-object solution for this, but personally I prefer to deal with hash tables.  You'll need at least v3 for the [PSCustomObject] type accelerator.  If it's V2, that will need to change to using New-Object.

```
$count = @{}
$size  = @{}

get-childitem *.txt |
 foreach {
           $date = $_.lastwritetime.tostring('dd-MMM')
           $count[$date]++
           $size[$date] += $_.length
         }
 $count.keys |
  sort|
  foreach {
           [PSCustomObject]@{
            Date = $_
            'Number of files' = $Count[$_]
            Size = $Size[$_]
           } 
         } | format-table -AutoSize
```

Comment: Great This gives exactly what I was looking for thank you, but could we format the hash table key value pair output like I have mentioned in the table. Currently I am getting output like

Current output - Name            Value
----            -----
Number of files 1
Date            07-Feb
Size            142
Number of files 1
Date            14-Feb
Size            3028
Number of files 2
Date            17-Feb
Size            279998
Number of files 1
Date            25-Feb
Size            0
Number of files 3
Date            27-Feb
Size            389

Comment: This one reads up ALL the files first into memory? I couldn't run it because of too many files

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution using `Group-Object`

```
$groups = get-childitem |select -Property FullName, length,@{Name="Updated";Expression={$_.lastwritetime.ToShortDateString()}}|group-object -property Updated;
foreach ($g in $groups) {
    $groupsize = 0;
    foreach ($item in $g.group) {
        $groupsize += Get-item $item.FullName | Select-Object -ExpandProperty length;
    }
    $g| Add-Member -name "Size" -MemberType NoteProperty -Value $groupsize;
}
$groups|select @{Name="Date";Expression={$_.Name}},@{Name="Number of Files";Expression={$_.Count}},Size|sort-object -property "Date" | Format-Table -AutoSize;
```

On my system it appears to be a bit slower than @mjolinor's method.

Comment: hi, your solution is great and practically it not taking much time in execution.
but looks like it is not able to group the files of same date. Probably because it is considering the complete time stamp in first line ie.e  group-object -property lastwritetime;.
Also I would like to thank you for putting your effor and time

Comment: I've revised to only look at the date, not the date & time.

Comment: Thank you solved now, your answer helped a lot. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: The script seems to be working great and as expected after you have modified. 
Thank you :).